# Package does not exist error even it is already imported in Java NetBeans

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, netbeans

I am trying to write a Java program using JDBC class to manipulate a MySQL database. I have imported the .jar file and customized the Drivers in 'Service' Part. However the a 'Package does not exist error' occurs when I trying to instantiating the imported MySQL Driver class by referencing the super-interface Driver. What can I do to fix the problem?

Here's my code and error pop-up:
[image]

Here's my database drivers setting in 'Service':
[image]

Comment: I don't know.  Can you provide a link to the page where you got these drivers?

Comment: @markspace https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/ Here's the download page for MySQL installer. The installer will guide you to download MySQL Connector/J in which a .jar file includes the Driver class.

Comment: Your first screenshot shows what appears to be the unzipped contents of the MySQL JDBC JAR file, located inside your application's "src" directory. That looks very strange - and I would not expect that to work, anyway.  Instead, you can add the JAR file (_not_ unzipped) to your project's "lib" directory. How you do this depends on how you are managing dependencies (e.g. using Maven, Ant/Ivy, Gradle, etc.). Side note: Using the "databases" and "drivers" services (your 2nd screenshot) is not a requirement to get JDBC integrated into your project.

Comment: @andrewjames This time I put the original .jar package inside the library/dependency. And the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.  Using the link you provided, I downloaded and installed the MySQL workbench thingy (whatever that is), and then located the Java driver under `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector J 8.0`.

I added that driver to a new NetBeans project (as a library, under *Library* right click and choose *Add Jar/Folder*) and it worked fine, with NetBeans even suggesting the packages as I typed them.

```
package stackoverflow;

/**
 *
 * @author Brenden
 */
public class JConnect {
   
   public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
      com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver driver = new com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver();
   }
   
}
```

[image: MySQL Connector file location]

[image: MySQL Connector in NetBeans]

Comment: After I added "throws Exception", the error message disappeared. Why is that?

Comment: I have no idea, that doesn't make any sense.  Perhaps it caused NetBeans to re-evaluate the method and notice that there were no problems?  I happen to be on the NB mailing list and they're voting on a candidate release for 12.2 right now.  (I lurk, I don't contribute.)  Perhaps they might be motivated to investigate this issue if you post there, since they are preparing for a release.